# Cannot change primary color when rendering

Tags: css, colors, bootstrap-4

The Bootstrap version is 4.4.1.
I'm also using fontawesome, v5.0.7.

I've created a `main.scss` file with the following contents:

```
$theme-colors: ( "primary": orange, "danger": purple );
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

This was compiled to `/css/main.css` that has:

```
:root {
    ...
    --primary: orange;
    ...
}

.text-primary {
    color: orange !important; }
```

So far, it seems fine.

In the html file, there's an import for the `main.css` style file.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css">
```

When trying to render text in orange, it is displayed in blue.

```
<p class="card-text text-primary">Some text.</p>
```

The browser dev tools show indeed that primary continues to be the blue color.
Where should I look for the cause of this?

Comment: When you are in dev tools, click the tab that says "computed". This will show you the list of applied CSS rules cascading through to your element. Find ```color```. The expand by clicking the arrow just to its left. This will show you all of the rules affecting the color. The ones that have been overridden will be crossed out in the order of precedence. The rule that won out, will not be crossed out and on top. Use that information to correct your situation by fixing the precedence or eliminating unneeded, overriding rules.

Comment: The blue color for `.text-primary` signaled with `!important` and comes from `_print.scss` line 54.  No signs of orange, though.

Comment: Try seeing how the CSS is compiled. View the source of the CSS file and see if it's missing your code.

Comment: The compiled `css`file seems right: `.text-primary { color: orange !important; }`

Comment: This seems solved to be a cache issue.  It's solved.  Thanks @BrentStees